# Hashcat | md5(md5($salt).md5($pass))

Tags: php, hashcat

I have a problem with hashcat, I was looking for Hash-Mode for a hash type

```
MD5(MD5($Salt).MD5($Password))
```

and I didn't find that Hash-Mode, I found only Hash-Mode 3910

```
md5(md5($pass).md5($salt))
```

but this is not what I need, there is a hash-mode that is suitable for cracking this type of hash what I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [filing a Github issue](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#i_want_to_request_some_new_algorithms_or_features_how_can_i_accomplish_this) to get the format supported.

Or you could try adding the format on your own? As suggested by [another forum post](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-4907.html) which links to [this git commit](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/commit/f0a84a2410fe5832ee120c3cbe62a84dca42b511) as an example. But this may be more effort that you planned to put into cracking your hash.